# Cannot get CORS working when trying to list bucket contents on Google Cloud Storage (404 not found)

Tags: google-api

I followed all the instructions and 'troubleshooting' guide for CORS but I have a feeling it's just not working.. i've spent the last 2 days just trying to list a bucket contents and not matter how i configure my CORS for my bucket it fails same way.

**What I'm using:**
 An angularJS client app talking directly to Google Cloud Storage using JSON API from my local machine (i.e. localhost)

**Followed all the advice here:**

https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin

**My Bucket:** 
gs://okrp-dev

**THE ERROR (chrome latest browser)**
XMLHttpRequest cannot load ***https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1beta2/b/okrp-dev/o***. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '`http://localhost`' is therefore not allowed access.

**My CORS file now (though i've tried every other permutation):**
bash-3.2$ gsutil cors get gs://okrp-dev

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<CorsConfig>
    <Cors>
        <Origins>
            <Origin>*</Origin>
            <Origin>    

    http://localhost</Origin>
        </Origins>
        <Methods>
            <Method>GET</Method>
            <Method>POST</Method>
            <Method>HEAD</Method>
        </Methods>
        <ResponseHeaders>
            <ResponseHeader>*</ResponseHeader>
        </ResponseHeaders>
        <MaxAgeSec>86400</MaxAgeSec>
    </Cors>
</CorsConfig>
```

**Trace from Chrome dev tools Network tab:**

```
Remote Address:74.125.193.132:443

Request URL:https://storage.googleapis.com/storage/v1beta2/b/okrp-dev/o

Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headers
:host:
storage.googleapis.com

:method:OPTIONS
:path: /storage/v1beta2/b/okrp-dev/o

:scheme:https
:version:
HTTP/1.1

accept:*/*
accept-encoding:
gzip,deflate,sdch

accept-language:en-US,en;q=0.8,tr;q=0.6

access-control-request-headers:access-control-allow-origin, accept, authentication

access-control-request-method:GET
cache-control:
no-cache

origin: 

    http://localhost    
pragma:
no-cache

referer:http://localhost/okrp/app/


Response Headersview source

alternate-protocol:443:quic
cache-control:
private, max-age=0

content-length:0
content-type:
text/html; charset=UTF-8

server:HTTP Upload Server Built on Mar 5 2014 15:51:04 (1394063464)

status:200 OK
version:
HTTP/1.1
```

**NOTE** I have the authentication working fine.   I'm no longer getting a 401.  Only 404.
**NOTE** I also of course totally opened up all permission on the bucket and object and that does not help at all.

How else can I troubleshoot this??